# Will this situation create a retain cycle

Tags: ios, objective-c

My sample code like this (just a sample):

```
[self.view touchActionWithCompeletion:^(NSSting *text){
    self.label.text = text;
}];
```

The block is a parameter of a method, the method is a instance method of `self.view`, then I access `self` in block. If `self.view` is a strong property, will this situation create retain cycle? And will `self.view` strong reference the block?

Comment: I think it should not, dead lock will happen only if you pass a string reference to block (in this case self) and then hold a strong reference to block itself. Hoping that method `touchActionWithCompeletion` will not save the block passed to it with a strong reference this should not result in a retain cycle :)

Comment: If you are storing the block as strong in your view class, It likely will create retain cycle, so should be careful and check if dealloc get called after pop the viewcontroller

Comment: @Tj3n The block is not a property, just a parameter of function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding my comment above as answer, after testing the code myself to confirm the logic I mentioned,

I think it should not, dead lock ( I mean memory leak, two strongly held objects holding the reference to each other and never being de-allocated hence I mentioned deadlock) will happen only if you pass a strong reference of an object to the block (in this case self) and then the passed object holds a strong reference to block itself (directly or indirectly).

Hoping that method `touchActionWithCompeletion` will not save the block passed to it with a strong reference this should not result in a retain cycle

**EDIT:**

Tested your code and deinit gets called as expected.
Here is what I tried,

```
class MyView : UIView {
    func touchActionWithCompeletion(block :(NSString)->()) {
        block("abcd");
    }
}

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {
    var myViewInstance = MyView()
    @IBOutlet var c: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.myViewInstance.touchActionWithCompeletion { (abcd) in
            self.c.text = abcd as String
        }
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit called")
    }
}
```

As expected deinit called.

Only thing to notice here, method `touchActionWithCompeletion` will not store the block passed to it with strong reference. It simply executes it. So my answer above holds true in this case.

**EDIT 2:(Clarifying my statement in answer)**

I happened mention **the passed object holds a strong reference to block itself (directly or indirectly)** I guess I need to explain why I mentioned **indirectly**.

Consider this case, Deadlock will happen if View holds a strong reference to the block passed to its method. Though the strong object passed here to the block is `self` and `self` does not hold the reference to block directly, it still result in deadlock if `View` holds a strong reference to block.

Reason **Self** *- holds a strong reference ->* **View** *- holds a strong reference ->* **Block** *- holds a strong reference ->* **Self**

Hence deadlock. Though `self` does not hold the block directly, because it holds the block indirectly, hence `deinit` on self will not be called. Hence I happened to mention **the passed object holds a strong reference to block itself (directly or indirectly)**

Hope it helps

Comment: You didn't access `self` in block.

Comment: @xm-zhang : I did not add it here lemme update my answer gimme a second

Comment: @xm-zhang : here you go, I updated my answer by accessing self, result still stays the same deinit gets called :)

Comment: Thx, in theory, the block is just a parameter of function, so it will be release when it outside funcion loop. In other words, block strong reference `self`,  `self` strong reference `view`, but `view` not strong reference block, so there is not a cycle.  I am right?

Comment: @xm-zhang : Bingo :) Correct,  Retain cycle will happen if view holds a strong reference to block, that case self -> view -> block -> self So dead lock :) read -> as holds strong reference to

Comment: @xm-zhang : Thanks buddy :)